# Preservation of Integral Closure under Localization.

Tags: commutative-algebra, ring-theory

Wikipedia says that if an integral domain $A$ is integrally closed, then $S^{-1}A$ is integrally closed if $S$ is a multiplicatively closed subset of $A$.  They state it as a reason for another argument but I can't figure out how to verify it as a standalone statement.

Using the hypotheses, it is straightforward (but notationally cumbersome so please forgive me for not posting it here) to show that if $y$ is integral over $S^{-1}R$, then $y$ is algebraic over $R$.  But this doesn't seem to help get me what I want.

I'm pretty sure that I need to use this fact for an equivalence of statements (for an integral domain) proof in a homework problem:

The homework problem:  $A$ is integrally closed if and only if $A_{P}$ is integrally closed for every maximal prime ideal $P$ of $A$. (Note I am not looking for help with this part quite yet as I think I can get it if I can verify the claim above.)

UPDATE:  Based on the argument below, I can conclude that if $y$ is integral over $S^{-1}A$
then there exists an $s\in S$ such that $sy$ is an element of $A$.  From here I want to conclude that $y = \frac{1}{s}sy \in S^{-1}A$.  But I'm a bit uncomfortable with the claim that $y = \frac{1}{s}sy$.  Unless I can write $y = y/1$, I cannot conclude this.  But I don't know anything about $y$ except that it is in the field of fractions in $S^{-1}A$.  Am I missing something trivial?

Comment: 1 is a multiplicative unit... it's hard to elaborate if you don't explain what particular issue you have about $y=y/1$.

Comment: Note that $\frac{1}{s}(\frac{ssy}{s})$ is certainly in $S^{-1}A$.

Comment: I don't know how to elaborate because I find this issue confusing.
I am always uncomfortable with the subtle identifications that are often happening.  Sorry I can't be more clear.

Do we identify $y/1$ with the product of the inverse of $1$ with $y$?

Comment: When confusion reigns, you could always *not* identify -- e.g. the first sentence of your update, did you really mean $(s/1) y = a/1$ for some $a \in A$? Anyways, we're in a commutative ring and $1$ is invertible, so division by 1 means multiplication by the inverse of 1. Also, maybe it would help to think about the fraction field $F$? With care, you can choose $F$ so that $A$ literally is a subring. Then, $S^{-1} A$ can be chosen to be another subring of $F$. (you may wish to prove that last statement)

Comment: Looking over your worry and your response again, I think something you missed is that $y = a/t$ for some $a \in A$ and $t \in S$, simply because $y \in S^{-1} A$: you don't *have* to try to write $y$ as $y/1$, since it's already a fraction.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough response.  I'd have to look it over again, but the core of the issue is that I'm trying to prove that $y\in S^{-1}A$.  It's already been verified that $y/1\in S^{-1}A$.  This is why I want to use the fact that $y = y/1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl: With one more apology for being so unclear, just as I was drifting off last night I thought of how to pin down why I am confused.

It seems to be obvious to everyone else that $y = \frac{y}{1}$.  But my problem is that I can't use the definition of equality in $S^{-1}A$ ($a/b = c/d$ if and only if there exists $e\in S$ such that $e(ad - bc) = 0$ in $A$) because I am not able to write $y$ as a fraction unless I assume that which I am trying verify.

I hope this makes more sense.

Comment: My mistake on the type of $y$ -- it was assumed to be in the fraction field of $S^{-1} A$ rather than in $S^{-1} A$. If the notation is still confusing you, could you explain where $y/1$ came from? I would have done the calculation more like $\frac{1}{s} s y = (\frac{1}{s} s)y = 1 \cdot y$.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2756/discussion-between-borninthe80s-and-hurkyl)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let $x$ be an element of the fraction field of $A$ which is integral over $S^{-1}A$. Thus $x$ satisfies some equation
\[
x^n + \frac{a_{n - 1}}{s_{n - 1}}x^{n - 1} + \cdots + \frac{a_0}{s_0} = 0
\]
with $a_i \in A$ and $s_i \in S$. Now, $s = s_{n - 1} \cdots s_0$ is an element of $S$. If you multiply the integral equation by $s^n$ and shuffle some things around, you should find that $sx$ is integral over $A$, hence is an element of $A$.

Comment: ahh!  i was multiplying by $s$ which wasn't doing the trick.  Thanks very much I will try this!  :)

Comment: update:  that was literally the step I needed.  thank you!

Comment: This is actually not completely true. You get equality with $0$ in the localization which implies that there exists $v\in S$ such that multiplying your polynomial with $v$ is $0$. So the same goes for multiplying your polynomial eith $v^n$ and then you shuffle stuff around and get $bsv$ is integral over $A$.

Comment: @Shaked In this case $A$ is an integral domain and $0 \notin S$, so $A \rightarrow S^{-1}A$ is injective. This means that $p(sx) = 0$ in $S^{-1}A$ implies that $p(sx) = 0$ in $A$.

Answer (score 9):

The Theorem in $\S 14.2$ of [my commutative algebra notes](http://alpha.math.uga.edu/%7Epete/integral.pdf) gives a slightly more general result:

Let $S/R$ be an extension of integral domains, and let $T \subset R$ be
a multiplicatively closed subset. Then the integral closure of $T^{-1} R$ in
$T^{-1} S$ is $T^{-1}$ (the integral closure of $R$ in $S$).

Applying this with $S$ equal to the fraction field of $R$ and $T$ equal to the multiplicative subset $S$ recovers the result you are asking about.