# Normal domain is equivalent to integrally closed domain. Is it true?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

> Normal domain is equivalent to integrally closed domain. Is it true?

Can anyone tell me?

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent for integral domains.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a solution to this problem for the sake of completeness.

Let $A$ be an integral domain with $K=Quot(A)$. We'll show it's normal (this is, for every prime ideal $p\subset A$ the localization $A_p$ is integrally closed) if and only if it's integrally closed.

- Let $A$ be normal and consider any $r\in K$ satisfying a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $A$. Then, since $A\subseteq A_p\subseteq K$, for ever prime ideal $p$ we know $r\in A_p$ for all $p$. Therefore 
  $$
  r\in\bigcap_{p\text{ prime}}A_p=A,
  $$
  where the last equality is shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/630752/an-integral-domain-a-is-exactly-the-intersection-of-the-localisations-of-a-a) or [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/825806/a-bigcap-mathfrakp-in-textspeca-a-mathfrakp-bigcap-math?noredirect=1&lq=1).

  - The converse follows from the fact that if $A$ is integrally closed then $S^{-1}A$ is integrally closed for any multiplicatively closed set $S$, as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/119124/preservation-of-integral-closure-under-localization).